# powershell command to remove entire line from a file matching pattern

Tags: powershell

Remove partial string matching line from a config file

Config file has below entries :

```
hello=path entry=990_342_33_0.1
hello=33321 entry=67889_44_33_0.1
hello=3332 entry=456_234_17_0.0
```

Expected output in config file :

```
hello=path entry=990_342_33_0.1
hello=3332 entry=456_234_17_0.0
```

Where : `$d = 44`

Command :

```
Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern 'entry=67889_$d_*_0.1' -NotMatch)
```

Nothing happens in above command execution but if we directly use the words instead $d or *, required output is obtained

Comment: The command is doing based on what is being written and thereby giving proper output and what you are expecting is already gotten out by wildcard.

Comment: PowerShell doesn't expand variable in single-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put the `-Pattern` string into double quotes (for more information on quotes: http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell_quotes.htm) but then `$d_33_0` is treated as the variable.

you therefore have to replace `$d` with `${d}`.

```
Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "entry=67889_${d}_33_0.1" -NotMatch)
```

Comment: by using Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "67889_.$d_33_0.1" -NotMatch) works fine but need in to work in below format
Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "67889_.$d_*_0.1" -NotMatch) with * in it to match any character in between

Comment: would the filter `67889_${d}_*` help? 

`Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "entry=67889_${d}_*" -NotMatch)`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(import-csv C:\Temp\config.txt -delimiter ' ' -Header Field1, Field2 | 
        where {($_.Field2 -split '_')[1] -ne '44'} | %{"{0} {1}" -f $_.Field1,$_.Field2}) | Set-Content C:\Temp\config.txt
```

Comment: will it include both $d and * criteria to match string in a line and remove the same

Comment: Like Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern 'entry=67889_$d_*_0.1' -NotMatch)

Comment: Replace 44 by $d

Answer (score 0):

If you simply use double quotes and put your variable in a SubExpression operator within the string, it will expand it correctly. I recomend using these SubExpression operators in all string to ensure you get the correct results.

They look like $($myVar)

For Example:

```
Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "entry=67889_$($d)_33_0.1" -NotMatch)
```

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2013/09/25/powershell-sub-expressions/

Comment: Set-Content -Path "file.config" -Value (get-content -Path "file.config" | Select-String -Pattern "entry=67889_$($d)_*_0.1" -NotMatch) where * in between should match any variable and it doesnot work in that criteria

Comment: can you share me the same command with only * character to detect in between ?